# How to disable debug messages in subversion 1.7?

Tags: svn

Ok, this is pretty basic, but I can't seem to find anything on this...

Subversion 1.7 prints debug messages on every error. This seems to be the default behaviour (several machines, I didn't change any options).

For example:

```
[~]% svn log
subversion/svn/log-cmd.c:674: (apr_err=155007)
subversion/libsvn_wc/wc_db.c:7439: (apr_err=155007)
subversion/libsvn_wc/wc_db.c:7439: (apr_err=155007)
subversion/libsvn_wc/wc_db.c:7439: (apr_err=155007)
subversion/libsvn_wc/wc_db_wcroot.c:514: (apr_err=155007)
svn: E155007: '/home/martin' is not a working copy
Exit 1

[~]% cd repo
[~]% svn rm nonexistent
subversion/svn/delete-cmd.c:92: (apr_err=125001)
subversion/svn/util.c:913: (apr_err=125001)
subversion/libsvn_client/delete.c:405: (apr_err=125001)
subversion/libsvn_wc/adm_ops.c:632: (apr_err=125001)
subversion/libsvn_wc/adm_ops.c:632: (apr_err=125001)
subversion/libsvn_wc/adm_ops.c:632: (apr_err=125001)
subversion/libsvn_wc/adm_ops.c:582: (apr_err=125001)
svn: E125001: '/home/martin/repo/nonexistent' does not exist
Exit 1
```

This seems to be new in subversion 1.7, IIRC 1.6 didn't do this.

Using **-q** doesn't help, and I can't [find any option](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.confarea.html#svn.advanced.confarea.opts.config) for this...

Answer (score 1):

If you need to remove it(my current case) use the following scenario:
Create the directory: /home/martin
svn revert --depth infinity {your_dir}
rm -r {your_dir}

Answer (score 0):

I am a Subversion command line tools user on Windows.  I needed to modify my `%APPDATA%\Subversion\servers` file to remove (comment out with leading `#`): neon-debug-mask = 130

For my config, debug output was only enabled for external SVN repos.  Internal repos did not output debug output.  You may have something similar in your config.